# Plot different functions as different axis on same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to put different functions plots on the same figure. Is that possible?
Overall, this is what I have tried:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
fig1, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2) 

x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,6,7,8]
z = [1,2,5,6]
def plot1(xcoord,ycoord,ax=None):
    ax=ax
    ax.plot(xcoord,ycoord)
    return plt.show()

def plot2(xcoord,ycoord,ax=None):
    ax=ax
    ax.plot(xcoord,ycoord)
    ax.grid('on')
    return plt.show()
doplot1(x,y,ax1)
doplot2(x,z,ax2)
```

I would like it to return with axis doplot1 on ax1 and doplot2 on ax2.
Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do what you want, would be:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def doplot1(xcoord, ycoord, ax=None):
    ax.plot(xcoord, ycoord)

def doplot2(xcoord, ycoord, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    ax.plot(xcoord, ycoord)
    ax.grid('on')

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [5, 6, 7, 8]
z = [1, 2, 5, 6]

fig1, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
doplot1(x, y, ax1)
doplot2(x, z, ax2)
plt.show()
```

Some remarks:

- When using `plt.subplots()` (not to be confounded by `plt.subplot()` without the 's'), there is no need to call `plt.figure()` as that is now done automatically.
- `plt.show()` should only be called after all the subplots have been created.
- `ax = ax or plt.gca()` can be used to check that when no `ax` is given (so being `None`) it gets the value of the current ax (`gca` means "get current axis").